# Máscara com Regex e replace para permitir apenas dígitos e um único hífen

Tags: c#, winforms, regex

**O que eu preciso:**

Uma máscara que funcione no evento `keypress` de um `TextBox` substituindo o que não é numérico e os hiféns excessivos por `""`.

**Qual minha dificuldade:**

Verificar a entrada de apenas um hífen na mesma expressão.

Cheguei na solução utilizando substring e somente funcionou no `KeyUP`, mas queria chegar através de uma expressão.

**O que já tentei:**

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

private static Regex digitsOnly = new Regex(@"(:?[^\d\-])");


private void inputSequencial_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(inputSequencial.Text)
   {
      inputSequencial.Text = digitsOnly.Replace(inputSequencial.Text, "");

      //MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(inputSequencial.Text, "[\\-]");
      //
      //if (matches.Count > 1)
      //{
      //    for (int i = 1; i <= matches.Count - 1; i++)
      //    {
      //         inputSequencial.Text = inputSequencial.Text.Substring(0, matches[i].Index-1) + inputSequencial.Text.Substring(matches[i].Index, inputSequencial.Text.Length);
      //         inputSequencial.Text = inputSequencial.Text.Replace(inputSequencial.Text[matches[i].Index].ToString(), "");
      //    }
      //}
   }
}
```

Resultado esperado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso conheçam formas melhores de fazer isso por favor me indiquem.
Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: poderia usar um `masktextbox` ?

Comment: Acredito que sim, estou migrando de outra linguagem para C#/WinForms então não conheço muito, vou pesquisar como funciona masktextbox.

Comment: isso. Só corrigindo: `MaskedTextBox`, aí você pode usar a mascára: `"0-000"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pesquisei aqui algumas alternativas, com Regex ou MaskedTextBox(Esse não me ajudou muito pois por padrão ele não é aceito em toolStrip local onde estava meu textBox).

No final das contas a melhor solução que encontrei foi tratando a entrada de valores a cada caracter da seguinte forma:

```
private void inputSequencial_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   //So permite a entrada de digitos(char 48 à 57), hífen (char 45), backspace(char 8) e delete(char 127)
   if ((e.KeyChar >= 48 && e.KeyChar <= 57) || e.KeyChar == 45 || e.KeyChar == 8 || e.KeyChar == 127)
   {    
      switch (e.KeyChar)
      {
         case (char)45:
         int count = inputSequencial.Text.Split('-').Length - 1;
         //Se for o primeiro caracter digitado no input ou 
         //se já existir um hífen evito a inserção.
         if (inputSequencial.Text.Length == 0 || count > 0)
         {
            e.Handled = true;
         }
         break;
      }
   }
   else
   {
      e.Handled = true; //Desprezo outras entradas
   }
}

private void inputSequencial_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   //Se o ultimo caracter for um hífen eu removo ele.
   if (inputSequencial.Text.Length > 1)
   {
      string lastChar = inputSequencial.Text.Substring(inputSequencial.Text.Length - 1, 1);
      if (lastChar == "-")
      {
         inputSequencial.Text.Replace("-", "");
      }
   }
}
```